# jQuery form validation that use html5 type attribute on fields

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm currently using "*Safe Form*" as jquery Plugin to real-time validate my webform.

I noted that almost all plugins like it does not use native modern browsers support of html5 input type fields and needs to add specific css class to form fields in order to detect what of them must be validated.

**I would like to integrate a plugin that detect html5 new types attribute** such as:

```
<input type='date'>
<input type='number'>
<input type='color'>
```

and fires validation directly on these. Maybe with native browser solution, if current browser have it, otherwise it should provide a fallback to old browsers.

I looked for a possible solution but I did not find nothing...

Comment: Which browsers are you aiming to build for?

Comment: Every. Obviously, Chrome, Firefox support html5 attributes but plugin should address also IE8 lack of support. In other words, plugin should use native browser support if present or provide a fallback in case of old browsers.